# Query output to xls through php does not work

Tags: php, mysql, xslt

We have a page created which would query a single table with plain "`select * from <table_name>;`" and provide the output in *XSL* format.
The code works fine in our *Dev* environment but fails in *Prod*.

```html
<?php require_once('Connections/cnca.php');
//create query to select as data from your table
$select = "SELECT * FROM fevisitdetails ";
        
//run mysql query and then count number of fields
$export = mysql_query ( $select ) 
       or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );
$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

//create csv header row, to contain table headers 
//with database field names
for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ ) {
     $header = mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . ",";
}

//this is where most of the work is done. 
//Loop through the query results, and create 
//a row for each
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) ) {
 $line = '';
 //for each field in the row
 foreach( $row as $value ) {
  //if null, create blank field
  if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) ){
   $value = "\t";
  }
  //else, assign field value to our data
  else {
   $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
   $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
  }
  //add this field value to our row
  $line .= $value;
 }
 //trim whitespace from each row
 $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
//remove all carriage returns from the data
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );


//create a file and send to browser for user to download
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fedetails.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";exit;
?>
```

Do you think I need to change any parameter for *Mysql/Php* to get this going?

Pls help...

Comment: "but fails in Prod" - please elaborate. side note: you have a tab delimited tabe in a text file, not an ".xls". Excel can import such data, but it's not application/vnd.ms-excel.

Comment: If you want to generate a csv file, then use PHP's built in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function rather than a bad homebrew

Comment: marked SQL query as code sample and emphasized technical abbreviations

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response...Well I admit , I'm not a php or mysql expert , as our developers on leave , there is nobody to assist us on this issue. while I set a limit to the above mentioned sql query it retrieves the data , but the max limit is 10k . Unfortunately the table has more than 13k records .

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the original code which seemed to fail in production you might be able to make use of the following. It uses a `mysqli` connection & functions - ( as the `mysql_*` family of functions are deprecated you are advised not to continue using them anyway ) and has several advantages over the mysql functions ~ for instance `fetch_fields()`

Rather than generating and concatenating a complex string use `fputcsv` - it is designed for the job so should save many headaches.

I cannot guarantee that this will resolve the issues you faced but it works for me in test and generates a 5000 row csv file very quickly.

```
ob_clean();

/* edit your db connection details */
$dbhost =   'xxx';
$dbuser =   'xxx'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'xxx';

/* safer & simpler with mysqli */
$conn   =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );        


$sql="select * from `fevisitdetails`;";
$res=$conn->query( $sql );

if( $res ){

    $headers=array();

    /* create a temporary file */
    $tmp = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'csv' );
    $out = fopen( $tmp, 'w');

    /* Fetch as array of objects - columns */
    $fields = $res->fetch_fields();

    /* Get the column / field names */
    foreach( $fields as $field ) $headers[]=$field->name;

    /* Add column headers */
    fputcsv( $out, $headers );

    /* Add each row ( array ) to the csv */
    while( $row=$res->fetch_array( MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){
        fputcsv( $out, $row );
    }
    /* close the file handle */
    fclose( $out );

    /* set headers and send csv data ~ works better with `.csv` extension */
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fedetails.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    /* echo data from csv */
    echo file_get_contents( $tmp );
    @unlink( $tmp );                

}
/* close db conn */
$conn->close();
exit();
```